# Power Apps, If statement for Single Line field

Tags: powerapp, powerapps-canvas

Does my datavaluecard have to be a dropdown for me to do this?

```
If( ThisItem.Status.Text = 'Submitted', DisplayMode.Disabled, DisplayMode.Edit)
```

I cant seem to get the "Status" column to = Submitted statement to be without error.

Comment: Just remove the `.Text` part if it is a text field

Comment: Im still getting an incompatible types for comparison. What could be wrong here?

Comment: Use double quotes around the word "Submitted", like this example `If(ThisItem.Title = "Submitted", DisplayMode.Disabled, DisplayMode.Edit)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `.Text` part and use double quotes around the value (`Submitted`), like this:

```
If(ThisItem.Title = "Submitted", DisplayMode.Disabled, DisplayMode.Edit)
```

Comment: thanks.. so simple!